# update table with distinct items SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I am creating a new table out of two existing table NSFABSTRACTS and AGENCIES. I want the result be word, their fileid, and org. If a word shows up more than once in a document. I want to capture it only once.I would like to first get all words in the new table and then update the word list based on unique fileid. Below is my query of capturing all of them

Before:

```
FILEID         WORD         ORG
1              HOW          OEC
1              TO           OEC
1              HOW          OEC
1              TO           OEC
2              YOU          DMS
2              YOU          DMS
```

After:

```
FILEID         WORD         ORG
1              HOW          OEC
1              TO           OEC
2              YOU          DMS
```

Here is the code.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP2(FILEID, WORD, ORG)AS
SELECT A.WORD, A.FILEID, B.ORG
FROM NSFABSTRACTS A JOIN AGENCIES B
ON A.FILEID=B.FILEID;

CREATE TABLE TMP(FILEID, WORD, ORG) LIKE TEMP2;
INSERT INTO TMP
SELECT DISTINCT FILEID, WORD 
FROM TEMP2 
GROUP BY FILEID, WORD;
```

The error happened to the second piece. Here is the message: `Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"`. It points to `INSERT INTO TMP`. Thanks.

Comment: `DISTINCT` must apply to the entire `SELECT` column list. `SELECT DISTINCT A.WORD, A.FILEID, B.ORG ` else use an aggregate with `GROUP BY`

Comment: I want to combine two table first and then keep all the words with distinct fileid. How do I edit the query? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP2(FILEID, WORD, ORG)AS
SELECT DISTINCT  A.WORD, A.FILEID, B.ORG 
FROM NSFABSTRACTS A JOIN AGENCIES B
ON A.FILEID=B.FILEID;
```

ie, the DISTINCT should be applied for every column of the table.

Comment: Would that lose some information. I wanted to have a list of all words with their fileid and org, and then keep words with distinct fileid. Thanks.

Comment: It will fetch the distinct rows from the tables. So if your table has duplicates then it would not take them. So in that sense you can say that it would loose some information :)

Comment: So I am trying to ignore DISTINCT function at this step then select only the distinct Word and update the table. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP2(FILEID, WORD, ORG)AS
INSERT TEMP2(FILEID, WORD, ORD)
SELECT DISTINCT  A.WORD, A.FILEID, B.ORG 
FROM NSFABSTRACTS A JOIN AGENCIES B
ON A.FILEID=B.FILEID;
```

Comment: I have the same question as for other answers: would this query lose some information. I wanted to have a list of all words with their fileid and org, and then keep words with distinct fileid. Thanks.

Comment: distinct on the whole select seems to be fine, if you have different WORD you would have that represented for every FILEID and ORG

Comment: So I am trying to ignore `DISTINCT` function at this step then select only the distinct Word and update  the table. How should I do that?